# Ruby equivalent of Python's `repr()`?

Tags: ruby, repr

Is there a Ruby equivalent of Python's `repr` method? I want to get a string representation of any given ruby object which lists all the attributes, their values, and all the methods.

I defined the following method, but I'm wondering if there is a more canonical way of doing this ...

```
def repr
  attrhash = {}
  instance_variables.sort.each {
    |v|
    attrhash[v] = instance_variable_get(v)
  }
  [ self, self.class.instance_methods.sort, attrhash ].to_s
end
```

Ideally, I'd like to not have to include this method into each and every class for which I want its `repr`-like data, and I'm wondering if there is a standard ruby mechanism to get this info for any given object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the helpful comments from `jeremy04` and `Jörg W Mittag`, I realize that there is nothing in Ruby which corresponds to `repr`, and that I can't make use of a simple `repr`-like method in all class instances without monkey-patching `class Object` itself. However, I realize that if I just make `repr` a standalone function, I can get the same functionality without monkey-patching and by doing `repr(obj)` instead of `obj.repr` whenever I want this info for a given object. The following stand-alone function works ...

```
def repr(obj)
  attrhash = {}
  obj.instance_variables.sort.each {
    |v|
    attrhash[v] = instance_variable_get(v)
  }
  {
    :string     => obj.inspect,
    :methods    => obj.class.instance_methods.sort,
    :attributes => attrhash
  }
end
```

I have this function return a hash instead of a string so that I can do things like this:

`repr(obj)[:attributes]`.

I can always do `repr(obj).to_s` if I want a string.

Also, I could make this into a class. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent of Python's `__repr__` in Ruby. At first glance, the closest thing may *appear* to be `#inspect`, because of these similarities:

> [This is typically used for debugging, […]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__)

and

> [Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of *obj*.](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-inspect)

But, there's an important difference:

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).

and

> [For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

Ruby's `#inspect` focuses on being *human-readable*, whereas Python's `__repr__` tries to be "`eval()`-round-trippable" (i.e. `eval(repr(e)) == e`), in other words, it should be *machine-readable*.

Comment: Thank you, but `inspect` doesn't show the names of the methods.

Comment: Yes, like I said, there is no equivalent in Ruby.

Comment: I know, and no criticism was intended for what you shared. I'm just clarifying, in light of what you explained, why `inspect` isn't enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

`inspect` is the closest equivalent to `repr` in Ruby, but it does not show public methods.

If you're looking for a tool instead: `pry` 
https://github.com/pry/pry

The `ls` command does exactly what you want.
You can also integrate pry into your irb / rails console as well.

Alternatively, you could monkey patch `class Object` with your method, but I feel like that's way too extreme of a choice, quite a few drawbacks.

Comment: `pry` looks quite useful. It offers a lot more than what I am asking for here, but that's fine. :)